# 2 methods in one java program

Tags: java, eclipse

I've created a program in eclipse but unfortunately, it exceeds the byte limit. I have found a way to solve this by using multiple methods but I have no idea how to create a new method or to have the program access the code in this method when I enter a command. I am making a text adventure game but I can't fit all the code I need into one class. I need to have the program execute a piece of code when I enter 'go east' on something else. Note that I am an almost complete beginner so try to dumb it down a bit please. I will put the person who helped me in the credits when I finish. Thankyou!

Comment: Perhaps you should start with [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: 1. Show us what you have tried.
2. Show any errors you encounter.
3. Check the link above and learn a bit more about the language.

Comment: *How* did you hit this limit?  I had to look it up since I've not fathomed encountering it...I would suggest posting your code here, but if it breaks the JVM limitations, I'd want to think otherwise for the time being.

Answer (score 5):

> I've created a program in eclipse but unfortunately, it exceeds the byte limit.

This should never happen. A method shouldn't be bigger than a page, and a class shouldn't be larger than several to perhaps 2 dozen methods.

> I have found a way to solve this by using multiple methods but I have no idea how to create a new method or to have the program access the code in this method when I enter a command.

This sort of information is usually to be found in the first few chapters of any basic Java textbook. Have you gone through a decent Java text book or tutorial before tackling this project? If not you may be getting the cart before the horse here.

> I am making a text adventure game but I can't fit all the code I need into one class.

Nor should you!

> I need to have the program execute a piece of code when I enter 'go east' on something else.

Not sure what you mean here.

> Note that I am an almost complete beginner so try to dumb it down a bit please. I will put the person who helped me in the credits when I finish.

Please tell them "my hovercraft has eels".

---

You will want to refactor what sounds like a monster class. I will bet that you've got a huge main method and that you're also mixing data with code. Understand that the code contains the fields to hold the program's *state*, and methods to show its *behavior* but the data holds the information used by the program to set its state. For instance for an adventure game, the data will hold the information about the rooms, the items in the room, and the program will hold the code that allows the user to move from room to room and to pick up items.

You will also need several classes. Some that you might need include:

- Room
- Map to hold all the Rooms
- Item -- and its subclasses
- Door -- this will connect one room with another
- Stairs? -- to allow more than one level?
- AbstractMonster
- Specific Monster subclasses
- Adventurer or user...
- Game or Driver -- the overall class that runs the simulation.
- IO classes to read in the data and to translate it into objects.
- User interface classes to allow interaction with the user.

I think that your best bet will be to perhaps put your large project to the side for a little bit, and then to pick up a couple of good Java books and go through them chapter by chapter to learn the rudiments of Java program design. And then after going through the books, come back to your project. I'll bet you'll see it in a whole new light.